# Add a caption to an external table

Tags: tables, captions, input

I have an external table that is is produced by a statistics package Stata like this:

```
sysuse auto
estimates clear
eststo, title("OLS"): reg price mpg
esttab using "~/Desktop/table.tex", replace title(My OLS Model)
```

The file `table.tex` looks like this:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{My OLS Model}
\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{c}}
\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{price}\\
\hline
mpg         &      -238.9\sym{***}\\
            &     (-4.50)         \\
[1em]
\_cons      &     11253.1\sym{***}\\
            &      (9.61)         \\
\hline
\(N\)       &          74         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I input it into a LaTeX main document like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\input{table.tex}
\end{document}
```

I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to add a note at the bottom of this table in the main document that could be edited in the main file (rather than modifying `table.tex` file)?
2. Is it possible to overwrite the caption from the main document?

Comment: Should the note be similar in width to the `tabular`? That is, just like the `\multicolumn` notes in `table.tex`?

Comment: @Werner No, I would like them to span the width of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using a `\label` inside the `table` to reference it, nor are you using the optional argument to `\caption` for a different LoT entry. So, we can just redefine `\caption` to do whatever you want, including supplying a new caption.

Additionally, we use [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch `\end{tabular}` for the insertion of arbitrary content via `\AfterEndEnvironment{tabular}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{table.tex}
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{My OLS Model}
\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{c}}
\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{price}\\
\hline
mpg         &      -238.9\sym{***}\\
            &     (-4.50)         \\
[1em]
\_cons      &     11253.1\sym{***}\\
            &      (9.61)         \\
\hline
\(N\)       &          74         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{booktabs,etoolbox}

\AfterEndEnvironment{tabular}{\tabularendstuff}
\newcommand{\tabularendstuff}{}

\begin{document}

% Update the \caption
\begingroup
\let\oldcaption\caption
\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{\oldcaption{A new caption}}
\renewcommand{\tabularendstuff}{\par {\footnotesize This is some arbitrary stuff added after \texttt{tabular}.}}
\input{table.tex}
\endgroup

% Original table
\input{table.tex}

\end{document}
```

All changes are grouped to limit their scope to the current `table`/`tabular`.