# How to add notes below external table (from esttab)?

Tags: tables, captions, notes, threeparttable

I am working on my first latex paper and am having trouble adding notes (describing the specifications, significance) below my regression table. I used esttab in Stata to create the .tex file I'm importing. I tried to use a three-way table but must have been doing something incorrect since I got an error, "Not in outer par mode", when I tried.

Here is what I have, which is working but doesn't give me notes:

```
{\renewcommand\normalsize{\scriptsize}%
\normalsize
\input{first_stage.tex}}
```

I found an answer that may be useful here ([Add a caption to an external table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333888/add-a-caption-to-an-external-table?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)), but the command it creates doesn't work for me (maybe because I'm bringing in an external table)? I've included it below in case it's helpful.

```
\AfterEndEnvironment{tabular}{\tabularendstuff}
\newcommand{\tabularendstuff}{}

\begingroup
\let\oldcaption\caption
\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{\oldcaption{First Stage}}
\renewcommand{\tabularendstuff}{\par {\normalsize My notes \texttt{tabular}.}}
{\renewcommand\normalsize{\scriptsize}%
\normalsize
\input{first_stage.tex}}
\endgroup
```

I would like to add a caption below the table saying "Notes:" and then the significance level, details on the specifications, etc. I imagine it would be more than one line. The external table does not have any table notes/exiting caption.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Does the external table have  a caption, or do you want to add one, in addition of the table notes?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out one method. `threeparttable` wasn't working for me because `esttab` automatically creates tables. I went into `first_stage.tex` and commented out the first and last line that create a table. I then could use the `threeparttable` command to add notes below my table.